# sql multiple where on join

Tags: mysql, sql

A have a table called `advert_property`

[image: pic1]

And I have a table `advert`, which is not important, advert properties connects to advert by `advert_id` column in `advert_property` table.

I wrote this SQL request :

```
SELECT * 
FROM `advert` 
JOIN advert_property ON advert.id = advert_property.advert_id 
WHERE (advert_property.property_id = 1 
       AND advert_property.property_value = "Манчего") 
  AND (advert_property.property_id = 2 
       AND advert_property.property_value = "козий")
```

What I want to get, is advert that have certain properties, for example : I want an idvert that have property_id = 1 and property_value = "Манчего" AND have property_id = 2 and property_value = "козий". SQL request returns null, how should I change my SQL request. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding your question correctly and you want to return all `adverts` that have ***both*** properties, then there are a couple ways of doing this using multiple `joins`, `exists`, `in`, `group by`...

Here is the method using multiple `joins`:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM `advert` a 
    JOIN advert_property ap ON a.id=ap.advert_id 
        AND ap.property_id = 1 AND ap.property_value = 'Манчего'
    JOIN advert_property ap2 ON a.id=ap2.advert_id 
        AND ap2.property_id = 2 AND ap2.property_value = 'козий'
```

Answer (score 0):

Query which you are trying to execute will never give you a result because it is trying to get a row with property id = 1 and property id = 2

For same row, there will never be two property_ids (1,2).

You need to review your where conditions.

My be what you need in where condition is as below(Either id will be 1 or id will be 2):

**Try this :**

```
(advert_property.property_id = 1 AND advert_property.property_value = "Манчего")
```

**OR**

```
(advert_property.property_id = 2 AND advert_property.property_value = "козий")
```

Comment: I understand that i should rewrite my where conditions, but how?

Answer (score 0):

You can't return all columns `*` where the `property_id` is both `1` and `2` because a record can't have two values for the same field. You can, however, return records where the `property_id` is `1` *OR* `2`. You could then have it only return DISTINCT `advert_id` where this is true:

```
SELECT DISTINCT advert_id 
FROM `advert` JOIN advert_property ON advert.id=advert_property.advert_id 
WHERE (advert_property.property_id = 1 AND advert_property.property_value = "Манчего") 
    OR (advert_property.property_id = 2 AND advert_property.property_value = "козий")
```